# How to profile a production android application

Tags: android, profiling

How to profile a production android application (apk) as its by nature not debuggable and will not show up in Eclipse DDMS or Android Monitor

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a tool (apk ) using which you can make a production ready code ready for code profiling . You can download the tool (performance profiler) at here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.testingoncloud.makeappdebuggable

One needs to install performance profiler from google play (link given above).

Steps -

1. Install performance profiler from google play store - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.testingoncloud.makeappdebuggable
2. Install the target app (say abcbank.apk )from playstore (which you want to profile) if its not already not done so.
3. Download the production (target app : say abcbank.apk) as apk on to SDCARD using apkshare

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newpower.apkmanager

4. Now uninstall the production (target) app which you want to profile(say abcbank.apk)
5. Start Performance Profilier app , which you have installed in step 1 and choose the target app from the grid below (its a file system access ). You can go to the sdcard location and choose the target app (say abcbank.apk) . You will get a confirmation message about your selection
6. Click on Install Target App Button . The targetProduction app now will be ready for profiling..

Closing Notes -

If you have any issues , you can contact me at indraneel_in@yahoo.com. Thanks for reading and have a great time code profiling